# XML parsing using XSL without xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to parse the following XML file content

```
<firstunit>
   <head>page</head>
   <para>ijkl</para>
   <para>mno</para>
   <para>xyz</para>
   <note>ask</note>
</firstunit>
<firstunit>
   <para>para</para>
   <head>head</head>
   <para>abcd</para>
   <para>mnop</para>
   <head>xyz</head>
   <note>askldj</note>
</firstunit>
```

Here the problem is,if i use

```
<xsl:for-each select="para">
```

i will get all the para tags first and then the rest.But i wont get the tags in order.Is there a way to traverse this XML and get all the tags in order?

Comment: Can you show the output you are actually expecting in this case, as it sounds like you want to do some sort of specific processing with `para` tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The usual push processing style coding in XSLT is to write templates and use `apply-templates`, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="firstunit">
  <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="head">
  <h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </h1>
</xsl:template>
```

That way you keep your code well-structured and the processing happens in document order.